# Trying to delete a list entry using different components

Tags: angular

I am trying to allow the user delete an item from a list of activities. I would like to emit an event from the item component of the app, which can then be used the root component. When clicking the delete button on the list item, nothing happens and i'm not sure why...

Here's the list component html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="new-item">
        <p class="desc">{{item.desc}}</p>
        <p class="start">{{item.start}}</p>    
        <p class="end">{{item.end}}</p>
        <button class="btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" (click)="deleteItem(item)"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

List component Typescript file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item: {desc: string, start: any, end: any} 

  deleteItemEvent = new EventEmitter();

  deleteItem(item) {
    this.deleteItemEvent.emit(item);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here's the App component html file:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
</div>
<app-users-input (gotUserInput)="afterUserInput($event)"></app-users-input> 
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="list">
        <app-item *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" (deleteItemEvent)="removeItem(i)" [item]="item"></app-item> 
    </div>
</div>
```

App component Typescript file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [];  

afterUserInput(serverData: {desc: string, start: number, end: number}) { 
  this.items.push({
    desc: serverData.desc,
    start: serverData.start,
    end: serverData.end
})

};

removeItem(item) {
  this.items.splice(item, 1);
}


}
```

There is another component which I haven't included here as I don't believe it is relevant. Hoping someone can help!

Comment: Instead of using events, you can pass the items property to the child component and loop on it there. That way, any changes you make to the Input property in the child will be reflected back in the parent, since a reference is passed. Be careful not to reassign the passed object. For ex, in child if you do items = [], the items in parent and child will no longer be the same. Instead, in child, do items.splice(0, items.length) if you want to empty the array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `@Output()` decorator for your event.

list-component.ts

```js
@Output() deleteItemEvent = new EventEmitter();
```

From the `@EventEmitter` [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter):

> Use in components with the @Output directive to emit custom events synchronously or asynchronously, and register handlers for those events by subscribing to an instance.

Comment: Of course! What a rookie error. I did know this, just slipped my mind. Thanks Kurt, will accept the answer once SO allows me to

Comment: @Kurt  i want to know one thing as i can see in  this.deleteItemEvent.emit(item); item is emitted whereas in app.component.html (deleteItemEvent)="removeItem(i)" in remove item index is passed. Both of these are different  than how it worked? as i know whatever will be emitted will be cached by corresponding event in parent? Please let me know if you know